# Reset variables in a function

Tags: python

I wrote a game in python, when the player finishes the game I want to return him to the main menu. In order to start a new game I want to reset all my variables to their first values before the main loop. I was thinking about inserting it into a function but then I have to set all my variables to global and there are a lot variables. Is there a way to set a function that all its variables are global automatically? Or that anyone has a different idea?

Comment: It's hard to give specific advice without seeing the code, but try creating all of your variables _inside_ the loop. Then when you return to the beginning of the loop, they'll all get re-created with their original values automatically.

Comment: That's really really long code.. But your idea seems fine to me.. I'll create a flag and ask inside the loop if it's true.. when it does i'll reset those variables.. Thanks!!

Comment: If you create the variables in a list, then you can return the list from the initializer function distributing it to the individual variables.

Comment: You could check the state design pattern http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html or embedd your game into a class gameWorld and simply create a new one when the game finish